# How do I group words found in string under the same value?

Tags: r

I have a column containing strings. I want to extract a particular word from it and if that word is found a value is assigned to it. This should work for all the strings present in it. Below is a vector which contains strings.(extracted from a data frame - data)

```
 [1] "What is TRAP"                                                                                                                 
 [2] "What are the limitations of SNMP v1"                                                                                            
 [3] "Compare between CMIS/CMIP and SNMP"                                                                                             
 [4] "Describe RMON standard"                                                                                                         
 [5] "What is ATM remote monitoring"                                                                                                  
 [6] "Describe ADSL configuration management"                                                                                         
 [7] "Describe different network management models and standards."                                                                    
 [8] "What are the functional requirements of NMS Design"                                                                             
 [9] "Explain with neat diagram SNMP v1 PDU format"                                                                                   
[10] "Compare between SNMP vl, SNMP v2 and SNMP v3"                                                                                   
[11] "Describe the capabilities of RMON2 in Enterprise network management."                                                           
[12] "Describe the serivices offered by CMISE"                                                                                        
[13] "SNMP proxy server "                                                                                                             
[14] "TMN conceptual model"                                                                                                           
[15] "Management Information Tree (MIT)"                                                                                              
[16] "Explain ADSL configuration management"                                                                                          
[17] "Describe RMON standard"                                                                                                         
[18] "Describe various parameters of managed objects"                                                                                 
[19] "What are challenges faced by network managers while managing a network"                                                         
[20] "What is fault management? Describe five steps process in fault management."                                                     
[21] "Explain physical architecture of TMN "                                                                                          
[22] " Explain all CMISE services in following categories: (i) Management association services (ii). Management notification services"
[23] "Write a note on management information tree (MIT)"                                                                              
[24] "Explain user security model of SNMPv3"                                                                                          
[25] "Discuss Network management tools "                                                                                              
[26] "Discuss Ml, M2 and M4 interface in ATM network management"                                                                      
[27] "List various event correlation techniques and explain an one in detail"                                                         
[28] "Explain configuration management with respect to network provisioning and network topology."                                    
[29] "Explain role of ADSL access network in overall network "                                                                        
[30] "Semi formal and formal notations"                                                                                               
[31] "SNMPv3 applications"
```

Looking at `[2], [3], [9] ,[10]` and so on we see "SNMP" is the common term here. I want to create another column and corresponding to strings having "SNMP" an integer value will be assigned. 
I used the grep function but it only return the indexes

```
> grep("SNMP",data$Questions)
[1]  2  3  9 10 13 24 31
```

I want to create a vector (let us say Value) with these indexes assigned the same value. How can I do it in one statement?

Comment: Check out `grepl`.

Comment: @Jota Thanks, this will work!